How do I plot $x^2+y^2=cx$?
I have recently started using Wolfram Mathematica. I am trying to plot this function
$$
x^2+y^2=c x
$$
for $c=0,2,4,8$. When I use Plot[{Sqrt[x - x^2]}, {x, -10, 10}], then the program in only plotting for the positive values in the first quadrant. Basically, $x^2+y^2=x$ is the general solution of the ODE $$2xyy'=y^2-x^2.$$
I would appreciate if someone could provide the entire code for solving and plotting the aforementioned differential equation.

ContourPlot

Maybe Plot[y[x] /. DSolve[2 x*y[x]*y'[x] == y[x]^2 - x^2, y[x], x] /.       C[1] -> # & /@ {0, 2, 4, 8} // Evaluate, {x, -10, 10},   AspectRatio -> Automatic]

ContourPlot works! Thank you @corey979.

This one works, too! Thank you @cvvgmt.


code
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 == c*x}, {x, -2, 8}, {y, -8, 8}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  ContourStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
 ,
 {{c, 2, "c"}, {2, 4, 8}, ControlType -> PopupMenu},
 TrackedSymbols :> {c},
 ContinuousAction -> False
 ]


I post this based on text of the question not the title. I apologise for errors. The stream plot is just for qualitative aspects (more than the implicit equation).
ode =DSolve[2xy[x]y'[x]==y[x]^2-x^2, y[x], x] 
i= y[x] ^2 /.ode
u = y^2 == i[[1]]
g1 = Show@@ (ContourPlot[Evaluate[u /.
С[1] → #],{x,-5, 5}, {y,-5, 5},
ContourStyle -> Red] &/@{0,2,4}); 
g2 = StreamPlot[{1, у/x -x /y}/2, {x,
-5,5}, {у,-5,5}];
Show[g1, g2]



Using *Region* functionality:
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == # x, {x, y}]
    , AspectRatio -> Automatic
    , PlotRange -> {{0, 64}, {-32, 32}}
    , BoundaryStyle -> ColorData[97, 1 + Log2[#]]
    , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02]
    ] & /@ PowerRange[1, 64, 2] // Show


Using Graphics:
{ColorData[97, 1 + Log2[#]], Circle[{#/2, 0}, #/2]} & /@ 
  PowerRange[1, 64, 2] // Graphics[#, Frame -> True] &



